# error setting up tileserver-gl on Nginx linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

trying to run tileserver-gl on nginx.

I modified the default config file accordingly

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /home/brian.tran/Documents/html;
# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

 location /Documents/project/POC_vector_tiles/ {
   proxy_pass http://localhost/8084/;
   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}



sudo service nginx restart
```

but when i restart nginx and navigate to localhost:80 it does not appear to run ----->

```
403 Forbidden
nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
```

trying to following the instructions on the tileserver-gl docs but not alot of examples on here ---> https://tileserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#running-behind-a-proxy-or-a-load-balancer

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Check the nginx error log.

Comment: You did nothing wrong. Your server runs. The HTTP 403 is a proper HTTP response. Additionally the server response seems to be correct, as you have allowed only URLs starting with http :// x.y.z /Documents/project/POC_vector_tiles/... 

In Nginx the location directive sets URLs you'd like to handle. This is a little different to Apache's configuration.